# No file permissions despite full permissions in sudoers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, system-administration

I have added the following to the file `/etc/sudoers` using the `visudo` command:

```
nick    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

But when I log in as `nick` and attempt something like `mkdir .ssh` I get:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.ssh’: Permission denied
```

Likewise, I cannot save files I have edited.

Running `ls -la` from the home directory gives me:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 nick nick 4096 Apr  7 19:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr  7 17:32 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 nick nick  220 Aug 31  2015 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 nick nick 3771 Aug 31  2015 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 nick nick 4096 Apr  7 18:29 .cache
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  7 19:07 .nano
-rw-r--r-- 1 nick nick  675 Aug 31  2015 .profile
```

Which if I'm not mistaken is showing that I have no write access to anything. (Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm only passingly familiar with UNIX permissions.)

Why can't this user do anything despite being given full permissions in `sudoers`?

**UPDATE:**

This problem fixed itself. I do not know what the problem was but it was no longer a problem when I logged on a couple days later.

For the record, I was attempting to configure a fresh DigitalOcean server running Ubuntu 15.10 x64. My local computer is a MacBook running El Capitan.

My guess is that the remote server restarted or somehow otherwise incorporated the change automatically in the interim. I had already tried running `sudo reboot` producing no results, so I'm still not sure how this could be.

I was also experiencing some local WiFi connection dropping at the time but as my SSH connection seemed to be operational I'm not sure if this could be related.

Comment: Did you try `sudo mkdir .ssh`? You've added him to sudoers, but do not use `sudo`?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about programming. You might be able to find help on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [the Unix & Linux StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not an expert to Linux, but to me it seems like you have to use `sudo mkdir .ssh` instead of `mkdir .ssh`. You allowed your user to behave like root(who has rights to write to directory), but for doing that you have to use `sudo` command.
Here is the simple explanation of how it works(with pictures): https://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html
Here is the serious documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers